# How to create a BrowserWindow in a VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron, vscode-extensions

I trying to create a electronjs [BrowserWindow](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window) in a VSCode extension but not yet successfull because of statement `const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron');` make the extension failed to load. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to show a custom dialog from my extension.

Answer (score 1):

VSCode does currently not allow extensions to access the Electron API. See also [#3011](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3011):

> The extension host is spawned as a regular node process (meaning only node API). It is very unlikely we will spawn it as an electron renderer (to give access to electron API).